# How to cache Video in WebView?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I have a `WebView` that loads an URL. I want that if URL has a video on it,it get cached for the first time. i wrote these codes:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
```

but it cached images and other thing except that video.
can somebody tell me why and how to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

I think I got the solution: to use cache, we usually write this:

```
settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true); 
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true); 
settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
```

the point is add this:

```
settings.setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*10);
settings.setAppCachePath(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath());
```

you should define the cache path.I tried and it works.I will Concerned about follow-up development